# Why is my render only showing the bounded mask area? (video editor)

Tags: edit-mode, video-sequence-editor, video, error

**Aim: Simply want to add a gaussian blur to my video.**

What i have already done, following a step-by-step using this link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NF_Q282V_uo:

- created the bounding box for the mask, with the name "privacy blur":

[image]

- added adjustment layer with the following settings:

[image]

- added gaussian effect strip on the video:

[image]

However after carrying out these steps, the gaussian effects works well **BUT** my render only displays the masked bounding box and everything else is hidden(shown below).

[image]

How do I rectify this?

Comment: Did you set the top strip to alpha over?

Comment: Applied alpha over to the "Adjustment" strip and it worked, THANKS!